# Spring boot app, need to set a database session variable before every transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot application that uses Hibernate/JPA entities. I need to run a bit of SQL to set a database session variable prior to each transaction. This session variable controls row level security at the database layer and so the SQL will use a web session parameter which I can retrieve from the spring web session context. I will need this bit of sql to run essentially before every transaction.

I'd like to be able to do this in a way that does not effect every additional piece of business logic. i.e. I'd rather not have to call the method manually from every repository class.

I saw the ConnectionPreparer class in the spring-data-jdbc-ext project (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc-ext/blob/master/spring-data-jdbc-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/support/ConnectionPreparer.java). However it appears this class is only called when the connection is first instantiated, not prior to every transaction.

Comment: Why not use aspect for that? You can write aspect that will be executed eg on start of every @Transactional method - it would be equivalent to manual invocation.

Comment: Maybe. But I would have no way to access the Connection object. Also it would get called far too often because Transactional methods can be nested and this only needs to happen at the start of a web request.

Comment: Create a wrapper for the `DataSource`. When a `getConnection`  is done (at the start of the transaction) then execute your sql before returning the connection. You also might want to run some SQL when close is called to cleanup the variables again (just to be safe).

Comment: @TheShoeShiner that is not a factor. All the constraints you have mentioned can be inspected directly in the code.